# Expose state and method of child Component in parent with React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ref

I know it's not a good pattern to do that, but you will understand why I want to do like that.

I have a `HTable`, which use a third-party library (react-table)

```
const HTable = <T extends object>({ columns, data, tableInstance}: Props<T>) {
   const instance: TableInstance<T> = useTable<T> (
   // Parameters
   )
   React.useImperativeHandle(tableInstance, () => instance);
}
```

Now, I want to control columns visibility from parent. I did:

```
const Parent = () => {
      const [tableInstance, setTableInstance] = React.useState<TableInstance<SaleItem>>();

      <Table data={data} columns={columns} tableInstance={(instance) => setTableInstance(instance)}

       return tableInstance.columns.map((column) => {
           <Toggle active={column.isVisible} onClick={() =>column.toggleHiden()}
       }
}
```

The column hides well, but the state doesn't update and neither does the toggle, and I don't understand why. Could you help me to understand?

EDIT:

Adding a sandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-imperative-ref-forked-dilx3?file=/src/App.js

Please note that I cannot use React.forwardRef, because I use typescript and React.forwardRef doesn't allow generic type like this if I use forwardRef

```
interface TableProps<T extends object> {
    data: T[],
    columns: Column<T>[],
    tableInstance?:  React.RefObject<TableInstance<T>>,
}
```

Comment: Looks like the code snippets you posted are a little mixed up. Can you correct these? Also, can you confirm that the tableInstance inside your Parent is re-set when you click your Toggle? - Would also be helpful if you can provide an example we can test!

Comment: i added a sandbox. Notice how the second checkbox doesn't update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `react-table`s `useTable()` hook always returns the same object as `instance` wrapper (the ref never changes). So your parent, is re-setting `tableInstance` to the same object - which does not trigger an update. Actually most of the contained values are also memoized. To get it reactive grab the `headerGroups` property.

```js
const {
  headerGroups,
  ...otherProperties,
} = instance;

React.useImperativeHandle(
  tableInstance,
  () => ({ ...properties }), // select properties individually
  [headerGroups, ...properties],
);
```

Comment: Coulc you provide a sandbox? When I do like that, I have an infinite rendering. And if I use createRef instead of useState, the problem remains.

Comment: @PaulSerre Your sandbox has an inline-function passed as a prop to `Table` on line 109 which triggers the re-render. Check [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-imperative-ref-forked-dvcjm?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you, really!
Last question, it is possible to do it with ref? It's a reusable component, so it would be more understable if it was with ref

Comment: Of course, you can just pass a ref instead of your setter function. The properties will be exposed at `ref.current.columns...`. But this ref will not be reactive / it won't re-render. You would have to find another way to get it reactive. That aside, to make it more understandable/reusable maybe you can find a way to move the table into its own custom-hook or make it accept children for the toggle buttons!

Comment: Thank you!
The last one I will not be able to dot it because I have to make an external button, meaning I have to be able to place it outside of the table :/